# How to pass exceptions globally to a single action from other actions in Struts 2

Tags: java, exception, struts2, xml-configuration, interceptorstack

I want to pass exceptions globally to a single action file called `ErrorAction`, say from `Index` action.

**Here's my `struts.xml` file:**

```xml
<global-results>    
    <result name="myErrorHandler" type="redirectAction">    
        <param name="actionName">myError</param>
    </result>    
    <result name="login" type="tiles">
        login
    </result>    
</global-results>    

<global-exception-mappings>    
    <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="myErrorHandler" />    
</global-exception-mappings>    

<action name="myError" class="com.actions.ErrorAction">    
    <interceptor-ref name="exception" />    
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />    
    <result name="error" type="tiles">error</result>    
</action>   

....    

<action name="Index" class="com.actions.Index">    
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />    
    <result name="success" type="tiles">home</result>    
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`exception` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/exception-interceptor.html) is already included in the `defaultStack`. Use the custom stack so that any exceptions not caught by the application will be logged and then handled by the global exception mapping

```xml
<interceptors>
  <interceptor-stack name="appDefaultStack">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
      <param name="exception.logEnabled">true</param>
      <param name="exception.logLevel">ERROR</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
  </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
<default-interceptor-ref name="appDefaultStack" />
```