# How to handle exceptions in a project using Struts 2, Spring, and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, exception, struts2

I want to know what is the better approach for handling exceptions. My web project is having Struts 2, Spring, and Hibernate.

An exception can occur either at Struts `Action` or at Biz Layer, or at Data Layer.

How to handle exception on each layer?

Comment: There is no general magic solution to exception handling.

Comment: See http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/exception-configuration.html.

Answer (score 0):

In the Struts, handling exceptions you might delegate to the framework (if you don't want to handle it manually) by defining a abstract default package that include a global exception handling.

And redirect to `error_page.jsp` when this exceptions occurred.

More detailed description you could find in [Exception handling in Struts 2 and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852089/exception-handling-in-struts2-and-hibernate/14859757#14859757):

> In the normal situation exceptions should be caught, logged and rethrown. But in the Struts2 you could handle uncaught exceptions via creating the default application interceptor stack
>
> ```xml
> <interceptor-stack name="appDefaultStack">
>  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
>    <param name="exception.logEnabled">true</param>
>    <param name="exception.logLevel">ERROR</param>
>  </interceptor-ref>
> </interceptor-stack>
> ```
>
> > any
> > exceptions not caught by this application will be logged and then handled
> > by the global exception mapping
>
> ```xml
> <global-exception-mappings>
>   <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error"/>
> </global-exception-mappings> >
> <global-results>
>   <result name="error">/error_page.jsp</result>
> </global-results>
> ```

See  [How to pass exceptions globally to a single action from other actions in Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751256/struts-2-how-to-pass-exceptions-globally-to-a-single-action-file-from-other-ac/14756187#14756187).